# Android Espresso Testing for matching text content between two EditTexts

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have created a Android app which has Login Edit Text & Password EditText with condition that if both contents in Login EditText & Password EditText matches then its true else false . How to test it using Espresso Unit Testing

I have used below code .

```
 @Test
    public void validLogin() {
        onView(withId(R.id.edtUserId))
                .perform(typeText(mStringToBetyped), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.edtPass))
                .perform(typeText(mValidPass), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.loginBtn)).perform(click());

      //  onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edtUserId))).check(matches(withText(String.valueOf(allOf(withId(R.id.edtPass))))));

        onView(withId(R.id.edtUserId)).check(matches(isEditTextValueEqualTo(R.id.edtPass, mStringToBetyped)));

     /*   onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edtUserId)))
                .check(matches(withText(String.valueOf(withId(R.id.edtPass)))));*/


        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Matcher<View> isEditTextValueEqualTo(final int viewId, final String content) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Match Edit Text Value with View ID Value : :  " + content);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (view != null) {
                String editTextValue = ((EditText) view.findViewById(viewId)).getText().toString();

                if (editTextValue.equalsIgnoreCase(content)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

But it gives me error for Matcher as seen below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.test.espressodemo.MainActivityTest$1.matchesSafely(MainActivityTest.java:90)
at com.test.espressodemo.MainActivityTest$1.matchesSafely(MainActivityTest.java:80)
at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:65)
at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:526)
at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$MatchesViewAssertion.check(ViewAssertions.java:103)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:415)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:279)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without using a custom matcher:

```
onView(withId(R.id.parentViewId)).check(matches(allOf(
            hasDescendant(allOf(withId(R.id.edtUserId), withText(mStringToBetyped))),
            hasDescendant(allOf(withId(R.id.edtPass), withText(mStringToBetyped)))
    )));
```

But since you're only comparing the text in 2 views, you can just use the Assert class as [Bach Vu mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569464/android-espresso-testing-for-matching-text-content-between-two-edittexts#comment95941370_54569518):

```
Assert.equals(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString())
```

Comment: That's a way to do it too :)

Answer (score 2):

The `view` inside your `isEditTextValueEqualTo` is actually `R.id.edtUserId`, so `view.findViewById(R.id.edtPass)` would return null.
There try changing to this

```
onView(withId(R.id.your_parent_view_that_has_edtPass)).check(matches(isEditTextValueEqualTo(R.id.edtPass, mStringToBetyped)));
```

if you really want to use custom `Matcher`, then how about this

```
Matcher<View> isEditTextValueEqualTo(final int viewId1, final int viewId2, final String content) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Match Edit Text Value with View ID Value : :  " + content);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (view != null) {
                String editTextValue1 = ((EditText) view.findViewById(viewId1)).getText().toString();
                String editTextValue2 = ((EditText) view.findViewById(viewId2)).getText().toString();

                if (editTextValue1.equalsIgnoreCase(editTextValue2)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

And in your test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.your_parent_view_that_has_edtPass)).check(matches(isEditTextValueEqualTo(R.id.edtPass, R.id.edtUserId)));
```

Comment: I need to check text inside edtUser matches with text inside edtPass

Comment: Weird, from your code I see that you want to check text inside `R.id.edtPass` vs `mStringToBetyped`

Comment: But if you want to check text inside 2 edit texts, just use `Assert.equals(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()`

Comment: I just realised something. @Yatin are you saying that the functionality of your app is that the user is able to log in successfully if the username matches the password (and that is what you want to test)?

Comment: Yes @ADroid ... exactly what i need

Comment: @Yatin in that case you just need to assert that the correct UI changes occur. So, for example, one test can check that an error message is displayed when the entered username doesn't match the password and vice-versa. You don't actually need to check the username and password in these tests, just the results.